# Google is showing a date from ten years ago in the search results when the page is much newer

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results

Recently I find out google shows my blog post with wrong date (1997)
I search content for this year(1997) but nothing found

[image: google search screen shot]

Sitemap

```
    <url>
        <loc>http://go2tr.com/blog/ZzNxAH34/گشت-و-گذاری-در-آنکارا-و-مراکز-دیدنی-آن</loc>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
        <lastmod>2018-09-26T13:23:22+00:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
```

what's the problem 
any idea?

Comment: Google doesn't use dates from the sitemap: https://www.seroundtable.com/google-lastmod-xml-sitemap-20579.html   If anything they take it from text on the page.

Comment: See also: [Google Rich Snippets showing the wrong date only for landing pages](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101109/google-rich-snippets-showing-the-wrong-date-only-for-landing-pages) and [SERP - Google Rich Snippets showing the wrong date for updated post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101116/serp-google-rich-snippets-showing-the-wrong-date-for-updated-post)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you translate the page to English (using Google Translate) then you have the text `01 مهر 97` at the top - that certainly looks like it has something to do with it.

As @Stephen suggested in comments they often fish the date out from on-page content - using some kind of "clever" (but seemingly flawed) algorithm.

See also:
[How does Google recognize publish date of a post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18395/how-does-google-recognize-publish-date-of-a-post)

Answer (score 2):

The reason might be is that you just updated your dates recently, now you have to wait until Google recrawls your site or you can force Google to recrawl your website

To force Google to recrawl your site *(usually takes several minutes)*:

1. Add your website is added to WebMasters console if it's not added,
2. then just go to:
   https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch
3. then fetch the page you want to recrawl or you can fetch the whole website

*You can use [this tool](https://www.seocentro.com/tools/search-engines/metatag-analyzer.html) to perform a Meta tags analysis, and check what is the date if your date is shown correctly, then just follow the steps I mentioned above to make it appear on the search results*

**Update:**

After reading @MrWhite's answer, I think that's the reason, it's inside a large-post-meta and you stated a date in it.

This is what I found by looking at the source of your page is that you have this div that has a date next to it

```
<div class="large-post-meta text-center">
<span class="avatar">نویسنده : نازنین صباحی</span>
<span><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> ۰۱ مهر ۹۷</span>
<span><a href="single-1.html#comments"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> 0</a></span>
<span><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> 16</span>
</div>
```

as you can see, it's a div with a post class: `<div class="large-post-meta text-center">` that has a date in it in this span tag: `<span><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> ۰۱ مهر ۹۷</span>`.

So I would advise you to use a [Schema Markup](https://moz.com/learn/seo/schema-structured-data) to force define your date and anyother information instead of Google just trying to guess it.

So your [date schema](https://schema.org/datePublished) markup is going to be something like this:

```
  <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2009-05-08">May 8, 2009
```

You can test it, and even try to add missing schemas using [Structured Data testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/) and [Structured Data Markup Helper](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/u/0/) provided by Google.